# Java regular expression with comma

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write regular expression for this pattern:

```
  String word="113(112,9)";
```

It should contains just numbers. Can any one help?

Comment: By the way, your example string doesn't contain _just_ numbers.

Comment: I beg to differ, Nishant. Keep in mind that questions and answers are not only for the immediate benefit of the one asking the question.

Comment: What is the pattern? Can you give an example string of what should and should match?

Comment: @Joey -- I'm all for community help. Here is the reason for what I commented (now removed by mods). 1. question is not clear, 2. I wanted to see if there made an honest attempt to solve it?, 3. Is OP respectful to the answerers? 

I personally think the question is too localized. Anyway, that's my POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work, without groups

`^[0-9]+\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)$`

and with groups

`^([0-9]+)\(([0-9]+),([0-9]+)\)$`

Answer (score 1):

If the number of digits is fixed as in your pattern, you can do this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\(\\d{3},\\d\\)");
System.out.println(p.matcher("113(112,9)").matches());
```

If the number of digits can vary, add limits to the `{...}` elements. For example, if the initial run of digits must be three to seven digits long, use `\\d{3,7}`